# Why is my average not the correct answer? (C code program to find mean)

Tags: c, floating-point, output, average, mean

I am bashing my head because I cannot figure out why my C code keeps printing the wrong average of a set of n numbers!

This is my code below:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int sum = 0.0;
    int lowest;
    int highest;
    float average;
    int range;
    int middle;
    double median;

    printf("\nEnter the amount of numbers you want?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int numbs[n];
    int temp[n];

    for(i = 0;i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a number from 0 to 15: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp[i]);
    }

    while (temp[i] < 0 || temp[i] > 15)  than 15
    {
        printf("This number is not from 0 to 15! Please re-enter another number: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp[i]);
    }

    numbs[i] = temp[i];
    sum += numbs[i];
}

int sortt = 0, j, x;

for (x = 1; x < n; x++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n - x; j++) {
        if (numbs[j] > numbs[j + 1]) {
            sortt = numbs[j];
            numbs[j] = numbs[j + 1];
            numbs[j + 1] = sortt;
        }
    }
}

lowest = numbs[0];
highest = numbs[n-1];
middle = n/2;

if (n % 2)
{
    median = numbs[middle];
}
else
{
    median = (numbs[middle - 1] + numbs[middle]) / 2.0;
}

average = sum/n;
range = highest - lowest;

printf("\nSum: %d", sum);
printf("\nAverage: %.2f", average);
printf("\nMedian: %.2f", median);
printf("\nRange: %d\n", range);

return 0;
}
```

This is my input and output below.  You can see that 8 divided by 3 is not 2, it is 2.67! I've tried using double and float.

Input & Output:

[image]

Comment: This is an ureadable mess. Learn properly formatting, it is the first state to write correct code.

Comment: `int sum = 0.0;` Let me guess, you compile without warnings enabled? Add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck...

Comment: `average = sum/n;` you are dividing two `int`s here. You need to say `average = sum/(double)n;` or it will be truncated.

Comment: The latter half of your code is not inside a function.

Comment: Everything is inside the main function. Yes, it is scattered I see.  Will clean it up once everything is finished.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: Clean it up BEFORE it is finished, else you will get confused and post confusing stuff to SO.

Comment: Pictures of text attract down votes. Text as text is useful for searching, cut and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the following line:

```
 average = sum/n;
```

to

```
 average = (float)sum/n;
```

You have to cast your return value into float. Think about it as a function with the following definition:

```
float divide(int x,int y){
     return x/y;  // returns an integer instead of float.
}
```

While this definition:

```
float divide(int x,int y){
     return (float)x/y;  // creates a temporary float variable and returns it immediately as the returned value of the function.
}
```

In addition, declaring `int sum=0.0`  is definitely going to show you a warning when compiling with `-Wall`. Try to follow warnings that you get from your compiler and fix all of them before you run your program.

Answer (score 0):

8 divided by 3 is 2, remainder 2. 8 and 3 are integers, and when you divide two integers, you use integer division with integer rules.

Also, this line might be confusing you:

```
int sum = 0.0;
```

Since `sum` is an `int`, this just sets `sum` to zero.

And:

```
average = sum/n;
```

Since both `sum` and `n` are integers, this is integer division. What you do with a result does not affect how that result is computed -- C's rules are complex enough already.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I wrote "0.0". Thank you, that went over my head!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Here see you can intake all values as float instead */ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 void main()
{
  float i,n,a,b,sum,ave;
  printf("This is a program to calculate the average of 'n' numbers \n");
  printf("Of How many numbers do you want to calculate average \n");
  scanf("%f", &n);
  printf("Enter the first number \n");
  scanf("%f", &a);
  sum = a;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
   {
    printf("Enter another number \n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    sum = sum + b;
   }
   ave = (sum/n);
   printf("The average of the %f number is %f", n, ave);
   getchar();
}
```